# Automatically execute the only goal of a maven plugin when it is included in the pom

Tags: java, maven, plugins, build, configuration

I have written a custom Maven plugin that generates some resources to be included in the final jar. The plugin is defined by a single `Mojo` class with a single goal `generate-files`.

I would like the users to **not** require defining any `execution` for the plugin, i.e. this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>A</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

should already **execute** the only goal (`generate-files`) during the default phase (`generate-resources`).

---

I have already attempted to define my new `lifecycle.xml` under `META-INF/maven` and the `components.xml` under `META-INF/plexus` but, as far as I understand, this only creates a new *packaging type*, which means that the above would work but I have to define `<packaging>my-custom-type</packaging>` and in this case my plugin is executed but no `jar` is produced because *only* the phases of my custom lifecycle get executed.

I would like my plugin to work with `jar`, `war` and `pom` packaging types (and produce `jar`s and `war`s etc.). Using custom packaging types means that I'd have to define `my-custom-type-jar` and `my-custom-type-war` and `my-custom-type-pom` etc. by copy&pasting the `jar`,`war`,`pom` etc. lifecycles and adding my custom phase...

This requires a lot of duplication, and, also, if the `jar` lifecycle gets updated I'd have to modify `my-custom-type-jar`.

Is it really that hard to just attach one goal of my plugin to a certain phase by default or am I missing something obvious?

Is multiple custom packaging types really the only way to achieve what I want?

Comment: The question is what kind of files you are generating? It might be a solution to define a parent pom where you already defined the binding with execution ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have already thaught of that, but I use a common pom already but not all projects should use this plugin. This would require defining multiple poms. Also some of my libraries/projects use a parent from a third party which I cannot modify but should still execute this plugin.